# Switching between currencies

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been fiddling with this problem for a long time, namely, how can I implement it so that switching between currencies works. I need the first select to have EUR, USD, GBP, and the second select to have UAH, GBP, EUR, but if I select EUR in the first select, then the second select should no longer have EUR, instead it appears USD, and also with other currencies. How can this be implemented?

```js
const [selectOne, selectTwo] = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-select');
const [symOne, symTwo] = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-select__option-symbol')
const [currencyOne, currencyTwo] = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-select__option--select');
const amountOne = document.getElementById('amount-one');
const amountTwo = document.getElementById('amount-two');
const rates = document.getElementById('rate');
const swap = document.getElementById('swap');

function converter() {
  const currency_one = selectOne.textContent.trim().slice(0, 3);
  const currency_two = selectTwo.textContent.trim().slice(0, 3);

  fetch(`https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {

      data.unshift({
        "txt": "Українська гривня",
        "rate": 1,
        "cc": "UAH"
      })

      firstCurrency = data.find(item => item.cc === currency_one);
      secondCurrency = data.find(item => item.cc === currency_two);

      rates.innerText = `1 ${currency_one} = ${(1 * firstCurrency.rate / secondCurrency.rate).toFixed(4)} ${currency_two}`;     
      amountTwo.value = (amountOne.value !== '') ? (amountOne.value * firstCurrency.rate / secondCurrency.rate).toFixed(2) : '';
    });
}

converter();

currencyOne.addEventListener('change', converter);
amountOne.addEventListener('input', converter);
currencyTwo.addEventListener('change', converter);
amountTwo.addEventListener('input', converter);

swap.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const [valueOne, valueTwo] = [selectOne, selectTwo].map(select => select.querySelector('.custom-select__option--select').dataset.value);
  amountOne.value = amountTwo.value
  selectOne.querySelector(`[data-value="${valueTwo}"]`).click();
  selectTwo.querySelector(`[data-value="${valueOne}"]`).click();  
  converter();
});

[...document.querySelectorAll(".custom-select")].map(select => {
  let selected = select.querySelector(".custom-select__option--select");
  if (selected) {
    select.dataset.value = selected.dataset.value;
    const placeholder = select.querySelector(".custom-select__placeholder");
    placeholder.innerHTML = "";
    const pho = selected.cloneNode(true);
    pho.classList.remove("custom-select__option--select");
    placeholder.appendChild(pho);
  }

  select.querySelector(".custom-select__list").addEventListener("click", e => {
    let target = e.target.closest(".custom-select__option");
    if (target) {
      let parent = target.closest(".custom-select");

      parent.querySelector(".custom-select__option--select").classList.remove("custom-select__option--select");
      target.classList.add("custom-select__option--select");
      let selected = parent.querySelector(".custom-select__option--select");

      parent.dataset.value = selected.dataset.value;

      const placeholder = parent.querySelector(".custom-select__placeholder");
      placeholder.innerHTML = "";
      const pho = selected.cloneNode(true);
      pho.classList.remove("custom-select__option--select");
      placeholder.appendChild(pho);
      target.closest(".custom-select").classList.remove("custom-select--drop");
    }
  });

  select.querySelector(".custom-select__placeholder").
  addEventListener("click", e => {
    let target = e.target.closest(".custom-select__placeholder");
    if (target) {
      target.closest(".custom-select").classList.toggle("custom-select--drop");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.custom-select {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
          z-index: 1;
          margin-bottom: 8.7px;
}

.custom-select:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

.custom-select__list {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% + 12px);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.custom-select--drop .custom-select__list {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
.custom-select--drop .custom-select__placeholder::after {
  transform: translateY(-80%) rotateX(360deg);
}
.custom-select__option {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 0;
}
.custom-select__option-icon {
  display: block;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.custom-select__option-icon img {
  display: block;
  width: 18px; 
  height: 15px;
  max-height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0;
}
.custom-select__option-name {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.custom-select__option-symbol {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.custom-select__option:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.045);
}

.custom-select__option--select .custom-select__option-name {
  color: #8dc641;
}
.custom-select__placeholder {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.custom-select__placeholder::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top-width: 6px;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #616161;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-30%) rotateX(180deg);
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.custom-select__option {
  padding-right: calc(1.5em + 10px);
}
.custom-select__option:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}



/* .container {
  
  border: solid 2px #212121;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
} */

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.indent-right {
  display: flex; 
  width: 24px; 
  height: 24px; 
  background-image: url("https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/ServiceCurrency.svg"); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: center center; 
  background-size: contain;
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 57px;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition-duration: 450ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  word-break: normal;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px 2px 4px 0px, rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px 0px 4px 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.swap-rate-container .btn-arrows {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  opacity: 0.54;
  transition: opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


.currency {
  padding: 40px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


input::placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px; 
}

.currency input {
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 65%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  margin-left: 15px
}

.currency input:hover {
  display:block;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

.currency input:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #8dc641;
}

/* .currency input::after {
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.currency input::before {
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.currency input:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.currency input:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
} */

.select-placeholder {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
}

.swap-rate-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.rate {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  line-height: var(--tl-small);
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none !important;
}

@media (maz-width: 600px) {
  .currency input {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Currency Converter</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="currencies-icon-10.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="indent-right"></div>
        <b>Конвертор валют</b>
      </div>
      <div class="currency">
      <div class="custom-select">
        <div class="custom-select__placeholder"></div>
        <div class="custom-select__list">
          <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="EUR">
            <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/EU.svg"/></div>
            <div class="custom-select__option-name">EUR</div>
            <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">€</div>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-select__option custom-select__option--select" data-value="USD">
            <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/US.svg"/></div>
            <div class="custom-select__option-name">USD</div>
            <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">$</div>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="GBP">
            <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/GB.svg"/></div>
            <div class="custom-select__option-name">GBP</div>
            <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">£</div>
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="UAH">
            <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/UA.svg"/></div>
            <div class="custom-select__option-name">UAH</div>
            <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">₴</div>
          </div> -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="number" id="amount-one" placeholder="200.00" />
      </div>

      <div class="swap-rate-container">
        <button class="btn" id="swap">
        <div class="btn-arrows">
        <div style="display: flex;">
          <svg
            height="24px"
            width="24px"
            version="1.1"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <g
              fill="none"
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              stroke="none"
              stroke-width="1"
            >
              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
              <path
                d="M6.99 11L3 15l3.99 4v-3H14v-2H6.99v-3zM21 9l-3.99-4v3H10v2h7.01v3L21 9z"
                fill="#000"
                fill-rule="nonzero"
              ></path>
            </g>
          </svg>
        </div>
        </div>
        </button>
        <div class="rate" id="rate"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="currency">
      <div class="custom-select">
        <div class="custom-select__placeholder"></div>
        <div class="custom-select__list">
          <div class="custom-select__option custom-select__option--select" data-value="UAH">
            <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/UA.svg"/></div>
            <div class="custom-select__option-name">UAH</div>
            <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">₴</div>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="GBP">
            <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/GB.svg"/></div>
            <div class="custom-select__option-name">GBP</div>
            <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">£</div>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="EUR">
            <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/EU.svg"/></div>
            <div class="custom-select__option-name">EUR</div>
            <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">€</div>
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="USD">
            <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/US.svg"/></div>
            <div class="custom-select__option-name">USD</div>
            <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">$</div>
          </div> -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="number" id="amount-two" placeholder="200.00" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: simply keep a conversion table, were you can select a `to` and `from` value for `x` currency against `y` currency.... then on the change event of either selection, then just pull the different, default to 1 currency, else if existing value, then just do the conversion

Comment: or else simplify your scenario and focus your question on how to change the selected element of a dropdown when the another dropdown has changed its value

Comment: @DiegoDeVita, Can you help with this issue? I need create an array with currencies in the js file?

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen, I need to create an array with currencies in a js file?

Comment: of course I could but it's annoying to find this exact snippet again and again in the past weeks. I can't even say it's the same person.. anyway if you want help from me on this matter, you need to strip off the details of that mess and just focus on two general dropdowns

Comment: @DiegoDeVita, What to strip off the details?

Comment: yes it's impossible indeed.. anyway I tried to play with your code trying to add the logic you were still missing so that when an option get selected on the first dd it gets hidden from the second. The problem was that it's very complicated to handle the nuances.. like deselecting an option from the second dropdown when you selected the same on the first. Your logic is messy there and was taking too long to figure it out.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita, And I also have a problem why my exchange rate does not change automatically when I switch currencies, it changes only if I do some action, it should also be 1 USD = 36.5686 UAH by default, but it shows 1 EUR = 37.4133 UAH , why? I realized that it takes the first blocks of divs, but I do not want to swap them, also I would like to show currency symbols instead of words, I tried to do it, but it only takes the first two icons.

Comment: in the end instead of trashing my previous findings I decided to share them as an answer.. but please people be friendly. That's not an answer and I clearly state it at the very beginning in bold. But it was important to do like that to show the evidence of what I just said before in the comments.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita, Wow, thanks, this certainly looks complicated, I need to understand in more detail, but why does this not work with the UAH currency. I also have a problem why my exchange rate does not change automatically when I switch currencies, it changes only if I do some action, it should also be 1 USD = 36.5686 UAH by default, but it shows 1 EUR = 37.4133 UAH , why? I realized that it takes the first blocks of divs, but I do not want to swap them, also I would like to show currency symbols instead of words, I tried to do it, but it only takes the first two icons.

Comment: the reason why there's no UAH currency among the options it's because I removed it (since it was commented in your html). The exchange rate doesn't change.. well because you embedded that logic in the `converter` function and you didn't call it in every occurrences where you should (for example at the end of the click handler of your selects). In general the logic should be refactored in a way to have functions performing specific actions to be called where all the events occur. It would take a while.. maybe one hour to be pretty sure of everything. Unfortunately today I cant help you that far

Comment: I felt pretty guilty today when I found you accepted the answer.. I'll spend some time later today to see if I can improve it

Comment: @DiegoDeVita, You what, you are not at fault in any way, I just accepted the answer so that it does not lie unanswered. It's rather my fault that, perhaps, I wrote the code incorrectly, which is now difficult to do what I want.

Comment: @andr_hot Posted now the working example... I began something that couldn't be left unfinished.  Good luck!

Comment: @DiegoDeVita, Thank you very much, they helped a lot, really complex code, I will deal with it, thanks again.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita, Sorry to distract you again, the fact is that the rate is a little incorrect, I mean that when you enter a number in the input, it calculates correctly, but every time I change currencies (pressing the arrow button) , different numbers are considered, they decrease, which should not be like this and it displays not 200, but 199, for example. Also, when changing currencies, all 4 currencies appear in the second drop-down list, which should be 3, and in the first 3.

Comment: I updated my answer to better explain the approximation producing that odd behaviour. I called that thing a minor drawback before.. now I just made the thing more explicit showing an exact scenario and why it's not easy to address. As per the latest thing you said about 4 options showing off when changing currency... that's not true. I'm not sure you are using the original snippet in my answer as is because that's not a behaviour I'm experiencing here. Consider that I used the trick of toggling the class `displaynone` that I added to your css.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita, But this is not correct when the number decreases when the course changes, I also understand when the number has changed only twice, at the first shift and at the second shift, but when the course decreases each time, this is not correct, because if in official converters enter a number, it will not decrease each time. As for the 4 currencies in the second drop-down list, you can check it yourself, just under my question, your answer, you can check it right there, click on the currency change button and open the first drop-down list and the second.

Comment: yes you were right about the 4 options. I apologize I didn't realize. I put so much efforts to invent that stupid trick that mimics the hanoi tower strategy when swapping currencies but didn't use the correct sequence. So now I applied the correct sequence and it should work correctly.

Comment: As per the approximation streategy your words show a lack of understanding of my explanation otherwise you would react differently. So I ask you.. did you understand correctly the scenario? do you get what's happening there? it's very simple mathematics. I have no idea how the official converters deal with it but if I have `a*b=c` despite I'd like that `c/b=a` it can't be perfectly true if in the meantime `c` was changed to a number with less digits after decimal point or even approximated to the nearest given digit. Maybe with a different approx. strategy it could be solved.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita, Please excuse me for disturbing you, you helped me a lot with this issue, but could you help me with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73221458/month-labels-instead-of-dates-on-the-chart

Comment: @diegod, But how to make it possible to also enter a number in the second input and it would also calculate the course, I mean, so that it would be possible to enter in both inputs and it would correctly count?

Comment: @andr_hot the reason why I decided on my own to make it only one way (input on first textbox and output on second one) it's because it's confusing why you should have a button for inversion and yet the possibility to write the input on both input boxes. It was adding confusion with no added benefit.

Comment: @andr_hot this question in total required a big effort from me.. and maybe I took some initiatives breaking requirements. But please don't forget that here we should deal with single problems to be solved. Wasn't the original question correctly answered already? Feel free to ask a new question if you are wishing further features to be better fine tuned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left pretty much untouched both the html and css styling apart some very few exceptions like the id defined for both the currency dropdowns for easier dom elements fetching and the second amount set as readonly to better fulfill the user experience.

The Javascript was refactored for better readability. Sometimes I may have changed your code in a way that look less cool but I preferred to have the state saved in DOM so that the functions were better encapsulated and didn't rely on variables defined outside of their scope.

This demo shows a working example of currency converter where the currency dropdowns are initialized in a way they don't overlap since the beginning and when each one changed its value, the corresponding option on the specular dropdown disappears. The event of changing currency on each of the two selects will refresh the currency rates displayed on the corresponding label and the value shown on the second amount. The value shown on the second amount gets refreshed, according to the currently selected currency conversion rate, also when the user is typing a new value on the first amount.

The swap trigger will swap the currencies position and will update the value shown in the whole gui.

***Side note:*** when swapping currencies, the values get recalculated and doing it again and again will show some odd approximations occurring that will produce a growing offset from the original input.

To better explain that problem, this is a scenario:

[USD=>EUR] [ratio E/$: 0.9783] [***102$*** * 0.9783(E/$) = ***99.7866***] [approx: ***99.79E***]

Now you don't have 99.7866 anymore but the approximated value ***99.79***, so:

[USD=>EUR] [ratio $/E: 1.0222] [***99.79E*** * 1.0222($/E)=***102.005338***] [approx:***102.01$***]

So as you can see with one step of swap we already got a ***0.01*** offset that will grow at each step everytime you swap.

And that's not the whole story. We are using floating point number to deal with currencies! And that's very wrong but in javascript the type `Number` holds value in floating point and it requires a further (big) effort to fix that.

But before that, it's impossible to get EXACTLY the previous value reverting the operation using the approximate value instead of the original value (that potentially had several digits after the decimal point).

I guess that's all.. I hope you'll have luck understanding the process I added there. It's mostly the same exact original architecture I found .. I just added something to make it work without scrambling its nature. I did my best to add comments that will help better understand.

```js
initializeAmount();
initializeSwap();
initializeCurrencyDropdowns();
refreshConversionRatesAndAmount();

/*******************************************************************************
 *  Initialize the amount for the first currency
 *******************************************************************************/
function initializeAmount(){  
  document.getElementById('amount-one').addEventListener('input', refreshAmount);  
}

/*******************************************************************************
 *  Initialize the Swap trigger already existing in DOM
 *******************************************************************************/
function initializeSwap(){    
  swap.addEventListener('click', () => {      
    
    const selectOne = document.querySelector('#cur1.custom-select');
    const selectTwo = document.querySelector('#cur2.custom-select');
    const amountOne = document.getElementById('amount-one');
    const amountTwo = document.getElementById('amount-two');
    const swap = document.getElementById('swap');    
    const [valueOne, valueTwo] =
      [selectOne, selectTwo].map(
        select => select.querySelector('.custom-select__option--select').dataset.value
      );
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Dirty trick to avoid problems when swapping currencies on the 2 DDs
    // by finding the currencies not chosen by the two dropdowns
    // and first selecting a third currency on the first dropdown
    // before doing the actual swap
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const availableCurrencies = [];
    const chosenCurrencies = [valueOne, valueTwo];
    selectOne.querySelectorAll('.custom-select__list .custom-select__option-name').forEach((o,i)=>{
      availableCurrencies.push( o.innerText );
    });
    const notChosenCurrencies = availableCurrencies.filter(c => !chosenCurrencies.includes(c));
    
    amountOne.value = amountTwo.value
    selectOne.querySelector(`[data-value="${notChosenCurrencies[0]}"]`).click();    
    selectTwo.querySelector(`[data-value="${valueOne}"]`).click();  
    selectOne.querySelector(`[data-value="${valueTwo}"]`).click();
    refreshConversionRatesAndAmount();
  });
}

/*******************************************************************************
 *  Initialize the Currency Dropdowns already defined in the DOM 
 *******************************************************************************/
function initializeCurrencyDropdowns(){
  //given the array of all .custom-select
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".custom-select")]
    //map()
    .map(select => {
      
      //inits dropdown options
      let selected = select.querySelector(".custom-select__option--select");
      if (selected) {
        select.dataset.value = selected.dataset.value;
        const placeholder = select.querySelector(".custom-select__placeholder");
        placeholder.innerHTML = "";
        const pho = selected.cloneNode(true);
        pho.classList.remove("custom-select__option--select");
        placeholder.appendChild(pho);
      }
      
      //adds click event listener to the list of options
      select.querySelector(".custom-select__list").addEventListener("click", e => {              
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Logic to hide from the other DD the selected currency in this DD
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //fetches information about the currently selected dropdown
        const thisDD = e.target.closest('.custom-select');
        const currencyCurrentlySelected = e.target.closest('.custom-select__option').dataset.value;    
        const currencyPreviouslySelected =
          thisDD.querySelector('.custom-select__option--select').dataset.value;

        //fetches information about the other dropdown
        const otherDD_id = ((thisDD.id == 'cur1' ? 'cur2' : 'cur1'));
        const otherDD = document.getElementById(otherDD_id);

        //removes the displaynone class to all the options in the other dropdown
        otherDD.querySelectorAll('.custom-select__option').forEach((o,i)=>{
          o.classList.remove('displaynone');
        });   
        //adds the class displaynone to the currently selected currency in the second dropdown    
        otherDD.querySelector(`.custom-select__option[data-value="${currencyCurrentlySelected}"]`)
          .classList.add('displaynone');
        
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
      
        let target = e.target.closest(".custom-select__option");
        if (target) {
          let parent = target.closest(".custom-select");
          parent
            .querySelector(".custom-select__option--select")
            .classList.remove("custom-select__option--select");
          target.classList.add("custom-select__option--select");
          let selected = parent.querySelector(".custom-select__option--select");
          parent.dataset.value = selected.dataset.value;
          const placeholder = parent.querySelector(".custom-select__placeholder");
          placeholder.innerHTML = "";
          const pho = selected.cloneNode(true);
          pho.classList.remove("custom-select__option--select");
          placeholder.appendChild(pho);
          target.closest(".custom-select").classList.remove("custom-select--drop");
        }
        
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        
        refreshConversionRatesAndAmount();
      });  
      
      //adds click event listener to the placeholder
      select.querySelector(".custom-select__placeholder").addEventListener("click", e => {
        let target = e.target.closest(".custom-select__placeholder");
        if (target) {
          target.closest(".custom-select").classList.toggle("custom-select--drop");
        }
      });
    });      
}

/*******************************************************************************
 * Refresh the conversion rates and converted amount (and metadata)
 * displayed in the respective labels
 *******************************************************************************/
async function refreshConversionRatesAndAmount(){

  const rates = await fetchConversionRates();
  
  const currencyOne = getSelectedCurrencyOne();
  const currencyTwo = getSelectedCurrencyTwo();
  
  const rateOne = rates[currencyOne];
  const rateTwo = rates[currencyTwo];
  
  const amountOne = document.getElementById('amount-one');
  const amountTwo = document.getElementById('amount-two');
  
  const rateLabel = document.getElementById('rate');
  
  const ratio = (1 * rateOne.rate / rateTwo.rate).toFixed(4);
  rateLabel.innerText = `1 ${currencyOne} = ${ratio} ${currencyTwo}`;       
    
  amountTwo.dataset.ratio = ratio;
  const newAmount = (amountOne.value * amountTwo.dataset.ratio).toFixed(2);
  amountTwo.value = (amountOne.value !== '') ? newAmount : '';        
}

/*******************************************************************************
 * Refresh the amount only 
 *******************************************************************************/
function refreshAmount(){
  const amountOne = document.getElementById('amount-one');
  const amountTwo = document.getElementById('amount-two');  
  const newAmount = (amountOne.value * amountTwo.dataset.ratio).toFixed(2);
  amountTwo.value = (amountOne.value !== '') ? newAmount : '';        
}

/*******************************************************************************
 * Fetch and return the conversion rates from a static url
 *******************************************************************************/
async function fetchConversionRates(){
  const url = 'https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json';
  const response = await fetch(url);   
  const rates = await response.json();  
  rates.unshift({
    "txt": "Українська гривня",
    "rate": 1,
    "cc": "UAH"
  });
  const ratesMapped = Object.assign({}, ...rates.map((rate) => ({[rate.cc]: rate})));
  return ratesMapped;
}

/*******************************************************************************
 * Returns the Currency code selected on the first currency dropdown
 *******************************************************************************/
function getSelectedCurrencyOne(){
  const cur1DD = document.querySelector('#cur1.custom-select');
  return cur1DD.textContent.trim().slice(0, 3);
}

/*******************************************************************************
 * Returns the Currency code selected on the second currency dropdown
 *******************************************************************************/
function getSelectedCurrencyTwo(){
  const cur2DD = document.querySelector('#cur2.custom-select');
  return cur2DD.textContent.trim().slice(0, 3);
}
```

```css
[readonly]{
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.custom-select {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
          z-index: 1;
          margin-bottom: 8.7px;
}

.custom-select:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

.custom-select__list {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% + 12px);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.custom-select--drop .custom-select__list {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
.custom-select--drop .custom-select__placeholder::after {
  transform: translateY(-80%) rotateX(360deg);
}
.custom-select__option {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 0;
}
.custom-select__option-icon {
  display: block;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.custom-select__option-icon img {
  display: block;
  width: 18px; 
  height: 15px;
  max-height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0;
}
.custom-select__option-name {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.custom-select__option-symbol {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.custom-select__option:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.045);
}

.custom-select__option--select .custom-select__option-name {
  color: #8dc641;
}
.custom-select__placeholder {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.custom-select__placeholder::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top-width: 6px;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #616161;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-30%) rotateX(180deg);
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.custom-select__option {
  padding-right: calc(1.5em + 10px);
}
.custom-select__option:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}



/* .container {
  
  border: solid 2px #212121;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
} */

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.indent-right {
  display: flex; 
  width: 24px; 
  height: 24px; 
  background-image: url("https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/ServiceCurrency.svg"); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: center center; 
  background-size: contain;
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 57px;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition-duration: 450ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  word-break: normal;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px 2px 4px 0px, rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px 0px 4px 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.swap-rate-container .btn-arrows {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  opacity: 0.54;
  transition: opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


.currency {
  padding: 40px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


input::placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px; 
}

.currency input {
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 65%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  margin-left: 15px
}

.currency input:hover {
  display:block;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

.currency input:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #8dc641;
}

/* .currency input::after {
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.currency input::before {
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.currency input:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.currency input:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
} */

.select-placeholder {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
}

.swap-rate-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.rate {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  line-height: var(--tl-small);
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none !important;
}

@media (maz-width: 600px) {
  .currency input {
    width: 200px;
  }
}

.displaynone{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Currency Converter</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="currencies-icon-10.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>      
  
    <div class="container">          
    
      <div class="header">
        <div class="indent-right"></div>
        <b>Конвертор валют</b>
      </div>
        
      <!-- Currency DD 1 -->
      <div class="currency">      
        <div class="custom-select" id="cur1">
          <div class="custom-select__placeholder"></div>
          <div class="custom-select__list">
            <div class="custom-select__option displaynone" data-value="EUR">
              <div class="custom-select__option-icon">
                <img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/EU.svg">
              </div>
              <div class="custom-select__option-name">EUR</div>
              <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">€</div>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-select__option custom-select__option--select" data-value="USD">
              <div class="custom-select__option-icon">
                <img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/US.svg">
              </div>
              <div class="custom-select__option-name">USD</div>
              <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">$</div>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="GBP">
              <div class="custom-select__option-icon">
                <img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/GB.svg">
              </div>
              <div class="custom-select__option-name">GBP</div>
              <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">£</div>
            </div>  
            <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="UAH">
              <div class="custom-select__option-icon">
                <img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/UA.svg"/>
              </div>
              <div class="custom-select__option-name">UAH</div>
              <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">₴</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
        <input type="number" id="amount-one" placeholder="200.00" />
      </div>
      <!-- END -->

      <div class="swap-rate-container">
        <button class="btn" id="swap">
          <div class="btn-arrows">
            <div style="display: flex;">
              <svg
                height="24px" width="24px" version="1.1"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" stroke-width="1">
                  <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
                  <path
                    d="M6.99 11L3 15l3.99 4v-3H14v-2H6.99v-3zM21 9l-3.99-4v3H10v2h7.01v3L21 9z"
                    fill="#000"
                    fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
        </button>
        <div class="rate" id="rate"></div>
      </div>

      <!-- Currenct DD 2 -->
      <div class="currency">      
        <div class="custom-select" id="cur2">
          <div class="custom-select__placeholder"></div>
          <div class="custom-select__list">
            <div class="custom-select__option custom-select__option--select" data-value="EUR">
              <div class="custom-select__option-icon">
              <img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/EU.svg">
              </div>
              <div class="custom-select__option-name">EUR</div>
              <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">€</div>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-select__option displaynone" data-value="USD">
              <div class="custom-select__option-icon">
              <img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/US.svg">
              </div>
              <div class="custom-select__option-name">USD</div>
              <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">$</div>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="GBP">
              <div class="custom-select__option-icon">
              <img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/GB.svg">
              </div>
              <div class="custom-select__option-name">GBP</div>
              <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">£</div>
            </div>          
            <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="UAH">
              <div class="custom-select__option-icon">
                <img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/UA.svg"/>
              </div>
              <div class="custom-select__option-name">UAH</div>
              <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">₴</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
        <input type="number" id="amount-two" placeholder="200.00" readonly="readonly" />
      </div>
      <!-- END -->
   
    </div>        
  </body>
</html>
```